# Import-Excel is showing a random string instead of the sheet

Tags: excel, powershell, sharepoint

I'm working currently on a project to automate some stuff. However I'm quited blocked with a problem in reading an excel file. I have an Excel file (related to MS Form so basically it does contain the results of a form ans it is shared on MS Sharepoint), I tried importing it using Powershell like this :

```
$value=Import-Excel "C:\Users\sth\sth1\MyFile.xlsx"
```

The problem is that `$value` gives me this as a result instead of the table:

```
TXzkw9Vz0Own80zEzjQhphDvtf05gBAi4P some other stuff
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Form1                                                                           
{d23c5acf-c4d2-47d5-9784-another random string}
```

FYI I did another test with another .xlsx file not linked to MS Forms and it worked.

EDIT:
`$value | Get-Member` gives this:

```
   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name                                                                             MemberType   Definition                                                                                   
----                                                                             ----------   ----------                                                                                   
Equals                                                                           Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                                               
GetHashCode                                                                      Method       int GetHashCode()                                                                            
GetType                                                                          Method       type GetType()                                                                               
ToString                                                                         Method       string ToString()                                                                            
cTXzkwEzjQhphDvtf05gBAi4PdtR-BB_JUOU5WSVFVTlFQNFZONERJQ1hGWDg1N0xOOS4u NoteProperty string cTXzkw9Vz0Own80zEzjQhphDvtf05gBAi4PdtR-BB_JUOU5WONERJQ1hGWDg1N0xOOS4u=Form1
```

EDIT 2:

The table in the excel should be like this

```
ID,    Email, Question1,Questin 2
----------------------------------
1    Email1  answer 1 Answer3
2    Email2  answer2 Answer 4
...
```

Does anyone has an clue about this ?

Thank you very much !!

Comment: Can you pipe your `$value` variable to `Get-Member` and share the output? `$value | Get-Member`

Comment: Hi thanks for responding, I'm going to modify the question

Comment: Just a couple more questions: can you share an example of what the output _should_ look like? Also, can you also run `$value | Get-Member` for the scenario where it is outputting _correctly_ to a table? Thanks.

Comment: Yes sure I'm editing it right now

Comment: Can you run `$value | Get-Member` again, but this time do it with the spreadsheet that is importing correctly? I'd like to see if there are any difference between working and non-working. Thanks.

Comment: The issue is cleary with the linked data as it does not obtain the data source when it reads the spreadsheet.